python multiprocessing.process is not launched in the emacs
My requirement is to launch a subprocess to process a CPU/memory task using python. As the subprocess is liable to fail causing it exited/killed by the OS. During the coding, I found the subprocess is never launched when using dap, and this is also verified using the following sample code:
import multiprocessing
from loguru import logger

class LogPrinter:
    @staticmethod
    def print_log():
        for i in range(10):
            logger.info(f"Subprocess is running {i}")
            

def main():
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=LogPrinter.print_log)
    process.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Start.....")
    main()
    logger.info("End...")

If the multiprocess/fork is not supported by Emacs, so what best practices to support it emacs? thanks.
